# what is it? my question is what's the meaning of img[img]

Tags: python, indexing

what's the meaning of new_image[new_image] in this image img in index what does it mean? and specify what img in index returns my image in this is gray scale

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umMGp.png)

Comment: `new_image` is a numpy array, and `new_image[new_image < 127] = 0` uses [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to set the values in the array that are less than 127 to 0.

Comment: Please post the code you are referring Tom without the code we cannot help